# The Command Prompt is not recognizing http

Tags: google-chrome, google-app-engine, sdk, cloud

I'm trying to install the Google App Engine.

I have Cloud SDK v260.0.0 and Python 2.7.9

When I run the command:

```
http://code.google.com/appengine/gcloud components install app-engine-python from the cmd
```

it gives me the error:

```
'http:' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What is going on?

I have Windows 10 and I'm running from the Directory:

```
C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Yanan C stated you install app engine with:

```
gcloud components install app-engine-python
```

However, I had to remove the link in the beginning.

Change:

```
http://code.google.com/appengine/gcloud components install app-engine-python
```

To:

```
gcloud components install app-engine-python
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [Guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/download#installing-cloud-sdk-for-python-2) to install app engine for Python 2.

Since you mentioned that Python and Google Cloud SDK have been installed, you might start from step 3 to run the following command in your terminal for the gcloud component:

```
gcloud components install app-engine-python
```

Comment: That's what I'm stuck on.